# AppEngine: Running Python code on the fly

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Hello Python developers!

I'm a Java one and I know that there is a way of running Java code on the fly, but my question is, is there any way to do that with Python?

The main goal here is to enable middle-school students to start coding with chromebooks from day one on Python.

I've been looking for some resources, but I got nothing so far.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you provide a clearer example of what you're looking for?  You can use exec to execute an arbitrary string, and eval to evaluate a string and get the value, but using either of them naively can be quite dangerous.

Comment: Sure, thanks for your comment! Actually I want to be able to execute code like a = 2, print 2. b = 3, print a+b. Make some if, for, statements and basic math..

Comment: Are you looking for something like http://ideone.com/ ? I don't understand what this has to do with AppEngine.

Comment: Wow, something like that, for sure! The idea of using AppEngine was to use google's environment to run the code, as users will be using lots of different OS. I don't want to spend time on setting up machines and kinda losing time on class with my students. I want something already set up, so I can introduce them to the dev world.

Comment: You mean like http://shell.appspot.com/ ? Are you happy to deploy one app per student, or do you want one multi-tenant app? The latter is harder, since you can't prevent people from breaking out of their sandboxes. What features are you looking for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://shell.appspot.com might be of your interest. (there's a link to the source code too)

Hey, I just recovered a link to a nice page I used in the past. It shows the execution flow of a Python script. Students I taught found it very useful in terms of comparing with other languages they new already, e.g. Java, how stack and arguments are being passed to the functions, memory allocations, etc:

http://people.csail.mit.edu/pgbovine/python/tutor.html

(click on "Visualize execution" button beneath the window with the code)

Answer (score 1):

[IPython](http://ipython.org/) allows you to run python interactively from a web environment.  You can try a demo here: [IPython](http://www.pythonanywhere.com/try-ipython/).  You can set this up on a local computer and have you students view it from their machines.

Answer (score 0):

[Coderbuddy](http://coderbuddy.com) let's you create and run AppEngine applications online, without having to download the AppEngine SDK, Python, or anything for that matter.

I use that when I do workshops, so I don't have to bother with making sure that everyone has the SDK and proper configurations in their machines. We just go straight to coding. :)